# Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500 Driver Update

Tags: drivers, mouse, windows-update, scrolling

Yesterday was the first time I had turned on my laptop in over a week, so immediately I started getting notifications that I needed to update stuff. So I update my antivirus, Adobe whatever, and then run Windows Update. (I run Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit). The two updates in the list of "Optional Updates" (or whatever the wording is) were both driver updates for my wireless mouse. As usual, I just updated everything (including the optional updates) and restarted my laptop.

Now here comes the annoying problem: Whenever I try to click the middle mouse button, instead of the usual thing happening (in a web browser it allows easy scrolling, in a Java IDE it takes you to the source code of whatever method/class name you clicked, etc), a small window opens, shows all of the windows I have open, and gives me about a 1/2 second to choose which window (out of the given windows) I would like to open (See screenshot below). I find this very annoying, and I have not found any way to disable it.

[image]

Note: The rest of the mouse works: Left click, right click, and plain scrolling are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to roll back the driver, to see if it is a new feature added in to the driver, or if it is something that Windows has decided would be best?

Comment: I'll try that...

Comment: yup that works. So I guess it's just a new feature added to the driver. It's kind of annoying though-- I don't know if the driver update is specifically for the new feature or if it also fixes any bugs.

Comment: Probably a bit of both.  You might install the updates one at a time, to see which one includes the feature you do not like, and which one is the one that does something that you might find more useful, or helps with other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The info, although fixing your issue is wrong and the driver is not at fault. The middle button can be configured to open numerous tasks, default is the Alt-Tab (quick switch) task box as shown in your image grab. To configure it to what you want you need to use the IntelliPoint Utility that usually gets installed upon first use along with the driver, alternatively download from Microsoft - version currently stands at 8.15 and download from here:

> http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/d/wireless-mobile-mouse-3500

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that they have changed the default function assigned to the middle button in the driver release.

As indicated, though not explained, the 'new' default function appears to be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (quick switch) which for one of my favorite pieces of software means it won't work.

Open the mouse properties window and try selecting 'Middle-click' as the default function.

Alternatively I note that there is an 'Enable program-specific settings' which would allow you to have the new default function for O.S and other programs but certain programs configured with custom behavior. - 08-Apr-2012 Subsequent to reading the above.